# SMTP blacklisted email response code

Tags: smtp

I am implementing a blacklist filter for a SMTP relay, which allows the user to define rules based on *sender email*, *receiver email*, *sender ip* or a combination of these. What SMTP status code should it reply if the email gets blocked because it is found to be blacklisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix defaults to handle reject_rbl_client blacklists by sending a 554 (Transaction failed) together with a textual explanation. A google search also suggest that being a rather common practice in dealing with blacklists.

Comment: I will use "554 5.7.1. Blacklisted"

Answer (score 0):

[filter-dnsbl](https://openports.se/mail/opensmtpd-filters/dnsbl), a dns-blocklist plugin for [OpenSMTPD](https://opensmtpd.org/) uses "421 Listed at ...". So for example when configured to use the Spamhaus Blocklist it returns `421 Listed at zen.spamhaus.org` if a server connects that is listed by Spamhaus.